# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I.m using pagedown editor in my project.

My HTML code:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/Markdown.Converter.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/Markdown.Sanitizer.js')?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/Markdown.Editor.js')?>"></script>


<div style="padding-top:20px;" class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input"></textarea>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div style="padding-top:20px;" class="control-group">
                    <label for="signature" class="control-label user-label">学校专业</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

and my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
        {
            var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
            var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
            editor1.run();
        });
</script>
```

google chrome browser throw out an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null ?", what's wrong in my code?

PS: appendChild is in the file of Markdown.Editor.js:1332

Comment: where is `appendChild` in your code?

Comment: which is the plugin used

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

Comment: @ArunPJohny it's pagedown editor  code.google.com/p/pagedown

Comment: Where did you initialize it,i.e. `new pagedown.Converter()` ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera in the javascript code i showed in my question.

Comment: var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
 var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `wmd-button-bar` element

From the Editot.js doc

> The second argument is optional, and is usually only necessary if
>   you're using several editors within the same page. If given, this
>   argument is a string, appended to the HTML element ids of the three
>   elements used by the editor. By default, the editor looks for  #wmd-button-bar, #wmd-input, and #wmd-preview. If you're using more than one editor, you of course can't give the second group of elements
>   the same ids as the first, so you may create the second input box as
>    and pass the string "-2" as the second
>   argument to the constructor.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CRcF9/)

Comment: Thank you! The error is gone now. But there is another problem that the button-bar is not shown in the browser?

Comment: @Charles see the css definitions sample for displaying the buttons https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/demo/browser/demo.css